# Borrowing ideas from poorly asked questions

Tags: discussion, community

I found a question today that had been closed today because of poor writing (too broad, not clear, etc) but the underlying idea was an interesting one. I'm pretty sure I could write a question to the same idea but in such a way that it won't be closed.

Clearly, writing a new question and posting it essentially "over top" the closed question is just rude. I don't want the idea to go to waste but rubbing someone's poor writing skills in their face isn't appropriate either.

What should I do about this?

Comment: Wait a week or two before posting it :-)

Answer (score 7):

A closed question doesn't have to be closed forever. You can try your best to edit it into shape instead, or you can wait a week or two before posting it. If you think you can edit the question without changing OP's intent, then do so. If you can't, then the reason for waiting is so that they have a chance to fix their own question first.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say: If you think you can edit the question without changing OP's intent, then do so. If you can't, then the reason for waiting is so that they have a chance to fix their own question first.

Comment: @Mourdos could you please integrate this comment into the answer?

Comment: @Lohoris No as it isn't my answer, but Aify is welcome to

Comment: @Mourdos I've done so. For future reference, if someone asks you to integrate something useful into an answer, don't worry about whether or not the answer is yours. This is a community site, and if the author doesn't like what you did he/she can always reject the edit or roll it back :)

Comment: @Aify In meta, answers are more of opinions, so I don't like tampering with out peoples opinions. But I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly advise to try to either convince the OP to improve his/her question or edit it yourself. If it's only a matter of grammar, do it right away.

A duplicate is a duplicate. I, for one, would not want to set a precedent. If, however, the OP isn't responsive after a reasonable effort, and no "simple" edit can fix the OP, then do ask your own.